# LuaLaTex produces beamer slides on variable speed

Tags: beamer, luatex

Why `LuaLatex` produces slides with speed depending on the number of them not on the complexity (still the same).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec,luacode,tikz}

\directlua{dofile("mwe.lua")}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% Produces slide very slowly
%\directlua{Scope(1)}

% Produces slide faste
%\directlua{Scope(5)}

% Produces slide even faster
\directlua{Scope(10)}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

and `mwe.lua`

```
tp = tex.print

function Scope ( n )
    for i = 0 , 360 , n
    do
        tp("\\visible<+-.(1)>{\\begin{scope}[rotate="..i.."]")
        tp("\\fill[blue] (0,0) rectangle (1,1) ;" )
        tp("\\end{scope}}")
    end
end
```

Comment: `beamer` scans each slide no matter the change among them. So it gets more and more complex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

beamer, while constructing the slides, always looks for what is visible and what is not at that particular slide number.

As an example, if there are three consecutive items appearing progressively as in the itemized lists etc. It constructs a slide with one item (and throws away whatever it sees as invisible), then constructs a slide with two items (and throws away the rest) and finally gets all of them (and throws away if something else disappeared in the meantime).

Hence what is actually being produced is three slightly different copies of the same code as individual pages. In a way it performs a for loop over the maximum number of pauses and `<-+>` it has seen so far and picks up the stuff that are marked as visible at that particular spin as a PDF page.

Thus, the compilation speed is related to the number of slides as each of them are processed as standalone genuine slides from scratch.